# Writing List(Variable) values to excel in Robot Framework?

Tags: excel, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have this piece of code which get all the names of similar Xpaths and places them a list variable and compares the list variable with another list variable to make sure all the data in the list variable matches. Now if the data matches I need to put this in an excel sheet and write PASS in the cell next to it and Fail beside the values that don't match. I am very new to robot framework please help.

```
*** Test Cases ***

Comparing data

    Open Browser 1 and Collect data
    Open Browser 2 and Collect data
    Log Browser 1 List
    Log Browser 2 List
    Compare
    Close allsesions of browsers

*** Keywords ***

Open Browser 1 and Collect data

    ${id_1}=  Open Browser    https://WWW.nyse.com  ${Browser_1}
    ${count_1}=  get matching xpath count  //*[@id="stats"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]
    : FOR    ${i}  IN RANGE  2  12
    \  sleep  10s
    \  ${j}   Get Text    //*[@id="stats"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[${i}]/div[1]
    \  Append To List    ${dbws_datapoints_1}    ${j}


Open Browser 2 and Collect data

    ${id_2}=  Open Browser    https://WWW.nyse.com  ${Browser_2}
    ${count_2}=  get matching xpath count  //*[@id="stats"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[1]
    : FOR    ${i}  IN RANGE  2  12
    \  sleep  10s
    \  ${j}   Get Text    //*[@id="stats"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[${i}]/div[1]
    \  Append To List    ${dbws_datapoints_2}    ${j}


Log Browser 1 List

    log  ${dbws_datapoints_1}

Log Browser 2 List

    log  ${dbws_datapoints_2}

Close allsesions of browsers

  close all browsers

Compare

    lists should be equal  ${dbws_datapoints_1}  ${dbws_datapoints_2}
```

Comment: What specifically are you having an issue with? You listed several things you are trying but didn't indicate which wasn't working. You should also include whatever error message you are currently getting or how the execution isn't meeting your expectations.

Comment: The above example does not comply with the StackOverflow recommended practice of providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The present example does not contain the actual Excel Library import, which means we can not determine which library is being used.  Also none of the excel write code that is troubling you is shown. It would be nice if we at least see that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

- Reference Excel library
- Third loop going through gathered data and logging it to the file

Comment: I refrenced Excel library.. But I am not sure how to loop through the list variable and place it in excel file. Please help

Comment: Here's the approach I would go for:

    :FOR    ${index}    IN RANGE    ${count}
    \    ${result} =    Evaluate    '${listA.__getitem__("${index}")}'=='${listB.__getitem__("${index}")}'
    \    Put String To Cell    sheetname=${sheetname}    index=${index}    row=${row}    value=${result}

Comment: I am sorry but I did not really understand this line Put String To Cell sheetname=${sheetname} index=${index} row=${row} value=${result}

Comment: It should just work if you have Excel library referenced, see: http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html#Put%20String%20To%20Cell

Comment: That was helpful.. Thanks